# glxgears gives Error: couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered visual on one remote server but not on another

Tags: ssh, x11, macintosh, opengl

The problem: I ssh to two remote clusters. By running `glxgears`, on one cluster I can successfully visualize the rotating gears though with some warning messages (details below), but on the other one it gives `Error: couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered visual` and nothing is visualized.

I have very little knowledge about OpenGL or X11 etc, so I'm not sure about

1. which one my problem is related to, OpenGL (and its driver?), my X11 software (XQuartz) or both.
2. whether it's a problem with my local machine or the cluster itself. I checked with another user on the cluster and everything works fine with him. He's also using a MacBook but not one with M1 chip and using the macOS 11.X (mine is macOS 12.0.1). I also tried using his shell rc file but it does not work for me.

**My local machine**

It is a MacBook Pro 16-inch 2021 with Apple M1 Pro chip.

- **Operating system**: macOS 12.0.1 (21A559)
- **Terminal**: Kitty terminal emulator / macOS Terminal
- **SSH binary** located at `/usr/bin/ssh`, the macOS built-in command.
- **X11 program**: XQuartz 2.8.1 (xorg-server 1.20.11), and since it's on macOS, the output of `defaults read org.xquartz.X11` is

```
{
    "NSWindow Frame x11_apps" = "316 70 454 299 0 0 1728 1079 ";
    "NSWindow Frame x11_prefs" = "531 375 484 370 0 0 1728 1079 ";
    SUHasLaunchedBefore = 1;
    SULastCheckTime = "2021-11-10 08:29:50 +0000";
    "app_to_run" = "/opt/X11/bin/xterm";
    "cache_fonts" = 1;
    "done_xinit_check" = 1;
    "enable_iglx" = 1;
    "enable_test_extensions" = 1;
    "login_shell" = "/bin/sh";
    "no_auth" = 0;
    "nolisten_tcp" = 1;
    "startx_script" = "/opt/X11/bin/startx -- /opt/X11/bin/Xquartz";
}
```

This is just to point out that I do have `"enable_iglx" = 1` as lots of solutions I found  ask people to run `defaults write org.xquartz.X11 enable_iglx -bool true`. This does not work for me.

**On the cluster where `glxgears` works**

`glxgears` gives the following messages

```
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib64/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib64/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: Can't open configuration file /etc/drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/hwu/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /etc/drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/hwu/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
40021 frames in 5.2 seconds = 7767.365 FPS
```

`glxinfo` gives the following messages

```
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib64/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib64/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: Can't open configuration file /etc/drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/hwu/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /etc/drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/hwu/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
name of display: localhost:12.0
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
display: localhost:12  screen: 0
direct rendering: No (If you want to find out why, try setting LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose)
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_visual_info, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_SGIS_multisample, 
    GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, 
    GLX_SGI_make_current_read
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_context_flush_control, GLX_ARB_create_context, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, 
    GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_buffer_age, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile, 
    GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
    GLX_MESA_swap_control, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, 
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, 
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, 
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync
GLX version: 1.4
GLX extensions:
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_OML_swap_method, 
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, 
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read
OpenGL vendor string: Apple
OpenGL renderer string: Apple M1 Pro
OpenGL version string: 1.4 (2.1 Metal - 76.1)
OpenGL extensions:
    GL_APPLE_packed_pixels, GL_ARB_depth_texture, GL_ARB_draw_buffers, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_program, GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow, GL_ARB_imaging, 
    GL_ARB_multisample, GL_ARB_multitexture, GL_ARB_occlusion_query, 
    GL_ARB_point_parameters, GL_ARB_point_sprite, GL_ARB_shadow, 
    GL_ARB_shadow_ambient, GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp, 
    GL_ARB_texture_compression, GL_ARB_texture_cube_map, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_add, GL_ARB_texture_env_combine, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar, GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3, 
    GL_ARB_texture_filter_anisotropic, GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat, 
    GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, GL_ARB_texture_rectangle, 
    GL_ARB_transpose_matrix, GL_ARB_vertex_program, GL_ARB_window_pos, 
    GL_ATIX_texture_env_combine3, GL_ATI_draw_buffers, 
    GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3, GL_EXT_abgr, GL_EXT_bgra, 
    GL_EXT_blend_color, GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate, 
    GL_EXT_blend_func_separate, GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_blend_subtract, 
    GL_EXT_clip_volume_hint, GL_EXT_draw_range_elements, GL_EXT_fog_coord, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_object, GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays, 
    GL_EXT_point_parameters, GL_EXT_rescale_normal, GL_EXT_secondary_color, 
    GL_EXT_separate_specular_color, GL_EXT_shadow_funcs, 
    GL_EXT_stencil_two_side, GL_EXT_stencil_wrap, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1, GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc, 
    GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp, GL_EXT_texture_env_add, 
    GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic, GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias, 
    GL_EXT_texture_rectangle, GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat, 
    GL_INGR_blend_func_separate, GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_depth_clamp, 
    GL_NV_fog_distance, GL_NV_fragment_program2, 
    GL_NV_fragment_program_option, GL_NV_light_max_exponent, 
    GL_NV_texgen_reflection, GL_NV_texture_rectangle, 
    GL_NV_vertex_program2_option, GL_NV_vertex_program3, 
    GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap, GL_SGIS_texture_border_clamp, 
    GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp, GL_SGIS_texture_lod, GL_SGIX_shadow_ambient, 
    GL_SGI_color_matrix, GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays

64 GLX Visuals
    visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
  id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x022 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x081 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x082 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x083 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x084 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  0  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x085 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x086 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x087 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x088 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  8  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x089 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x08a 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x08b 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x08c 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  0  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x08d 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x08e 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x08f 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x090 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  8  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x091 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x092 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4  0  0  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x093 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 32  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x094 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 32  0  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x095 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x096 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4  0  8  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x097 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 32  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x098 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 32  8  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x099 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x09a 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4  0  0  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x09b 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 32  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x09c 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 32  0  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x09d 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x09e 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4  0  8  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x09f 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 32  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x0a0 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 32  8  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x0a1 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a2 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0a3 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a4 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0a5 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a6 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0a7 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a8 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0a9 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0aa 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0ab 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0ac 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0ad 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0ae 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0af 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0b0 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b1 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0b2 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2 32  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b3 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2 32  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0b4 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b5 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2  0  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0b6 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2 32  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b7 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2 32  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0b8 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b9 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0ba 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2 32  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0bb 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2 32  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0bc 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0bd 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2  0  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0be 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2 32  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0bf 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2 32  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None

64 GLXFBConfigs:
    visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
  id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x041 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x042 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x043 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x044 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  0  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x045 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x046 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x047 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x048 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  8  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x049 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x04a 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x04b 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x04c 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  0  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x04d 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x04e 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x04f 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x050 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  8  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x051 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x052 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4  0  0  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x053 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 32  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x054 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 32  0  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x055 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x056 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4  0  8  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x057 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 32  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x058 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 32  8  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x059 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x05a 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4  0  0  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x05b 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 32  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x05c 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 32  0  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x05d 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x05e 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4  0  8  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x05f 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 32  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x060 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 32  8  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x061 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x062 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x063 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x064 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x065 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x066 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x067 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x068 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x069 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x06a 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x06b 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x06c 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x06d 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x06e 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x06f 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x070 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x071 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x072 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x073 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2 32  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x074 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2 32  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x075 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x076 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2  0  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x077 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2 32  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x078 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2 32  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x079 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07a 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x07b 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2 32  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07c 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2 32  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x07d 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07e 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2  0  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x07f 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2 32  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x080 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2 32  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
```

**On the cluster where `glxgears` does NOT work**

`glxgears` gives the following messages

```
Error: couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered visual
```

`glxinfo` gives the following messages (by the way, `export LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose` does not provide any more information)

```
name of display: localhost:29.0
display: localhost:29  screen: 0
direct rendering: No (If you want to find out why, try setting LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose)
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_visual_info, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_SGIS_multisample, 
    GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, 
    GLX_SGI_make_current_read
client glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_context_flush_control, GLX_ARB_create_context, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_no_error, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, 
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_buffer_age, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile, 
    GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_stereo_tree, GLX_EXT_swap_control, 
    GLX_EXT_swap_control_tear, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_NV_copy_buffer, 
    GLX_NV_copy_image, GLX_NV_delay_before_swap, GLX_NV_float_buffer, 
    GLX_NV_multigpu_context, GLX_NV_multisample_coverage, 
    GLX_NV_robustness_video_memory_purge, GLX_NV_swap_group, 
    GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGI_swap_control, 
    GLX_SGI_video_sync
GLX version: 1.4
GLX extensions:
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, 
    GLX_SGIX_pbuffer
OpenGL vendor string: Apple
OpenGL renderer string: Apple M1 Pro
OpenGL version string: 1.4 (2.1 Metal - 76.1)
OpenGL extensions:
    GL_ARB_depth_texture, GL_ARB_draw_buffers, GL_ARB_fragment_program, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow, GL_ARB_imaging, GL_ARB_multisample, 
    GL_ARB_multitexture, GL_ARB_occlusion_query, GL_ARB_point_parameters, 
    GL_ARB_point_sprite, GL_ARB_shadow, GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp, 
    GL_ARB_texture_compression, GL_ARB_texture_cube_map, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_add, GL_ARB_texture_env_combine, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar, GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3, 
    GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat, GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, 
    GL_ARB_transpose_matrix, GL_ARB_vertex_program, GL_ARB_window_pos, 
    GL_EXT_abgr, GL_EXT_bgra, GL_EXT_blend_color, 
    GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate, GL_EXT_blend_func_separate, 
    GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_blend_subtract, GL_EXT_draw_range_elements, 
    GL_EXT_fog_coord, GL_EXT_framebuffer_object, GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays, 
    GL_EXT_rescale_normal, GL_EXT_secondary_color, 
    GL_EXT_separate_specular_color, GL_EXT_shadow_funcs, 
    GL_EXT_stencil_two_side, GL_EXT_stencil_wrap, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1, GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc, 
    GL_EXT_texture_env_add, GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic, 
    GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias, GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_depth_clamp, 
    GL_NV_fog_distance, GL_NV_fragment_program2, 
    GL_NV_fragment_program_option, GL_NV_light_max_exponent, 
    GL_NV_texgen_reflection, GL_NV_vertex_program2_option, 
    GL_NV_vertex_program3, GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap, GL_SGIS_texture_lod

64 GLX Visuals
    visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
  id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x022 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x081 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x082 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x083 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x084 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  0  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x085 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x086 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x087 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x088 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  8  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x089 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x08a 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x08b 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x08c 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  0  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x08d 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x08e 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x08f 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x090 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  8  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x091 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x092 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4  0  0  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x093 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 32  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x094 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 32  0  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x095 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x096 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4  0  8  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x097 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 32  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x098 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 32  8  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x099 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x09a 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4  0  0  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x09b 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 32  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x09c 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 32  0  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x09d 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x09e 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4  0  8  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x09f 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 32  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x0a0 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 32  8  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x0a1 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a2 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0a3 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a4 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0a5 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a6 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0a7 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a8 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0a9 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0aa 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0ab 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0ac 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0ad 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0ae 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0af 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 32  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0b0 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b1 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0b2 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2 32  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b3 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2 32  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0b4 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b5 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2  0  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0b6 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2 32  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b7 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2 32  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0b8 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b9 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0ba 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2 32  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0bb 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2 32  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0bc 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0bd 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2  0  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0be 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2 32  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0bf 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2 32  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None

32 GLXFBConfigs:
    visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
  id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x041 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x042 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x045 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x046 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x049 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x04a 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x04d 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x04e 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x051 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x052 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4  0  0  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x055 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x056 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4  0  8  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x059 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x05a 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4  0  0  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x05d 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 Slow
0x05e 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4  0  8  0  0  0  0 16 1 Slow
0x061 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x062 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x065 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x066 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x069 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x06a 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x06d 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x06e 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x071 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x072 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x075 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x076 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2  0  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x079 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07a 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x07d 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07e 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  2  0  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We encountered this issue recently and solved it by running `export __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=mesa` in the ssh session. For some reason it was loading the nvidia opengl driver despite the mac not having any nvidia hardware. There's probably some way to fix this on the mac instead, but temporary solutions are permanent.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

I have uninstalled XQuartz:

`launchctl unload /Library/LaunchAgents/org.xquartz.startx.plist sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.xquartz.privileged_startx.plist sudo rm -rf /opt/X11* /Library/Launch*/org.xquartz.* /Applications/Utilities/XQuartz.app /etc/*paths.d/*XQuartz sudo pkgutil --forget org.xquartz.pkg`

Then I reinstalled it and since then everything works again.

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Unfortunately, this does not solve my problem.